# Sort an arraylist of objects by one of the properties?

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

Hi I have an object called item here is the code for it:

```
Public Class item
Private itemValue As String
Private urlfoundValue As String
Private typeValue As String
Private scorevalue As String
Public Sub New()
    ' Leave fields empty. 
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal item As String, ByVal urlfound As String, ByVal type As String, ByVal score As String)
    itemValue = item
    urlfoundValue = urlfound
    typeValue = type
    scorevalue = score
End Sub

Public Property item() As String
    Get
        Return itemValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        itemValue = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property urlfound() As String
    Get
        Return urlfoundValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        urlfoundValue = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property type() As String
    Get
        Return typeValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        typeValue = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property score() As String
    Get
        Return scorevalue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        scorevalue = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I have an ArrayList of these items that I would like to sort in highest to lowest order by the Score property (is string but can be converted to int32).

The items are all store in this arraylist:

```
Public fullitem As New System.Collections.ArrayList()
```

Any suggestions on how to get the items in order by the score? Can be done in c# too.

Comment: use a `List(Of Item)` / `List<Item>`  and avail yourself of the wonderful world of extension methods such as `OrderBy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct answer to your question is to use LINQ like this:

```
Dim orderdList = fullitem.Cast(Of item)() _
    .OrderBy(Function(i As item) Convert.ToInt32(i.score))

fullitem = New System.Collections.ArrayList()

For Each item In orderdList
    fullitem.Add(item)
Next
```

This uses `Cast` to obtain a generic `IEnumerable<item>` from the `ArrayList` which then enables you to use LINQ functions like `OrderBy`.

However, please note that `ArrayList` is now obsolete, and you should consider using `List<Item>` instead. If you do that then you can do something as simple as this:

Assuming you have the list defined like this:

```
Dim list = new List(Of item)()
```

You can sort it like this:

```
list = list.Cast(Of item)() _
    .OrderBy(Function(i As item) Convert.ToInt32(i.score)) _
    .ToList()
```